# GitHub reusable workflow not found when using tag

Tags: github, workflow

I'm trying to learn how to use reusable workflows and started writing one which [runs unit tests](https://github.com/ZIMO-Elektronik/.github-workflows/blob/master/.github/workflows/ctest.yml)

```
name: ctest

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      target:
        description: 'CMake test target'
        default: ${{ github.event.repository.name }}Tests
        required: false
        type: string

jobs:
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc.yml
    with:
      target: ${{ inputs.target }}
      upload-artifact: true

  ctest:
    needs: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/download-artifact@v3.0.2
        with:
          name: build.tar
          path: .
      - run: tar -xvf build.tar
      - run: ctest --test-dir build --schedule-random
```

This workflow itself references another local workflow called `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc.yml` which performs the actual build of the target before running the test driver. So far so good.

If I try to use this workflow from another repository this works as long as I reference the branch

```
jobs:
  tests:
    uses: ZIMO-Elektronik/.github-workflows/.github/workflows/ctest.yml@master
```

But once I reference it using tag [v0.0.1](https://github.com/ZIMO-Elektronik/.github-workflows/tags) the runner complains that the referenced local workflow does not exist

```
jobs:
  tests:
    uses: ZIMO-Elektronik/.github-workflows/.github/workflows/ctest.yml@v0.0.1
```

And I'm getting the following error message

```
error parsing called workflow ".github/workflows/tests.yml" -> "ZIMO-Elektronik/.github-workflows/.github/workflows/ctest.yml@v0.0.1" (source tag with sha:c23f5c8f48bf22556705346de61cbca499db5839) --> "./.github/workflows/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc.yml" : workflow was not found. See https://docs.github.com/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows#access-to-reusable-workflows for more information.
```

Answer (score 1):

What the... for some reason this has to do with the type of git tag you're using, see ->

> However, we figured out that if we use only a lightweight Git tag
> (rather than an annotated git tag), it works. So, as a result, for
> GitHub Workflows repositories, we need to avoid using annotated tags.
> This seem not possible to forbid as a configuration, so we need to be
> careful.

https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/48693#discussioncomment-6132963